# Transform array of object to include sumTotal of certain keys and new properties

Tags: javascript

I need to transform an array of objects to include only specific keys, sum of keys, and some new keys.

Notice a) the inclusion of months keys, b) a `TotalAmount` key, and c) sum of amounts matching category and month.

How do I go about it? I don't suppose there is a single function I can leverage but I'm unable to decide which ones I should use and in which order. I'm new to object manipulation and so also wonder which methods would be more performant versus the others. I intend to run this logic on client-side i.e. on modern browsers so hopefully, they should be able to process without much impact on user experience.

Also, note that the categories are not fixed and need to be reduced based on the input i.e. original payload.

Any help is much appreciated!

Before:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "dfCategory": "category 1",
    "dfAmount": 200,
    "dfCreatedForMonth": "1",
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "dfCategory": "category 2",
    "dfAmount": 200,
    "dfCreatedForMonth": "3",
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "dfCategory": "category 1",
    "dfAmount": 200,
    "dfCreatedForMonth": "3",
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "dfCategory": "category 3",
    "dfAmount": 200,
    "dfCreatedForMonth": "3",
  },
  {
    "id": "5",
    "dfCategory": "category 2",
    "dfAmount": 200,
    "dfCreatedForMonth": "5",
  },
]
```

After:

````
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "dfCategory": "category 1",
    "TotalAmount": 400,
    "Jan": 0,
    "Feb": 200,
    "Mar": 0,
    "Apr": 200,
    "May": 0,
    "Jun": 0,
    "Jul": 0,
    "Aug": 0,
    "Sep": 0,
    "Oct": 0,
    "Nov": 0,
    "Dec": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "dfCategory": "category 2",
    "TotalAmount": 400,
    "Jan": 0,
    "Feb": 0,
    "Mar": 0,
    "Apr": 200,
    "May": 0,
    "Jun": 200,
    "Jul": 0,
    "Aug": 0,
    "Sep": 0,
    "Oct": 0,
    "Nov": 0,
    "Dec": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "dfCategory": "category 3",
    "TotalAmount": 200,
    "Jan": 0,
    "Feb": 0,
    "Mar": 0,
    "Apr": 200,
    "May": 0,
    "Jun": 0,
    "Jul": 0,
    "Aug": 0,
    "Sep": 0,
    "Oct": 0,
    "Nov": 0,
    "Dec": 0
  },
]```
````

Comment: Where are these other objects keys and values coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce`.

```js
const arr=[{id:"1",dfCategory:"category 1",dfAmount:200,dfCreatedForMonth:"1"},{id:"2",dfCategory:"category 2",dfAmount:200,dfCreatedForMonth:"3"},{id:"3",dfCategory:"category 1",dfAmount:200,dfCreatedForMonth:"3"},{id:"4",dfCategory:"category 3",dfAmount:200,dfCreatedForMonth:"3"},{id:"5",dfCategory:"category 2",dfAmount:200,dfCreatedForMonth:"5"}];
const getMonth = idx => {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setMonth(idx);
  return d.toLocaleString('en', {month: 'short'});
};
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {id,dfCategory,dfAmount,dfCreatedForMonth})=>{
    acc[dfCategory] ??= Object.assign({id,dfCategory,totalAmount:0},
     ...Array.from({length:12}, (_,i)=>({[getMonth(i)]: 0})));
  acc[dfCategory][getMonth(dfCreatedForMonth)] += dfAmount;
  acc[dfCategory].totalAmount += dfAmount;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: It works! I don't get it how haha but I'll be dissecting it to learn its inner workings. Thanks for posting your solution @iota. I don't suppose you'd have enough time to explain it too?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma the categories IDs are wrong BTW.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed but as long as they are unique they work. Though I’ll modify the code to straight them up. Thanks Roko.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion for a cleaner solution:

- Uses [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store the unique Categories instances
- Uses a [Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to construct instances of `Category` categories
- Uses a Class `static` property to ensure every category gets an incremented `id` value
- Provides a reusable Method `addAmount(monthNum, value)` to add a value to a specific Month

```js
class Category {
  static id = 0;
  static m = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  constructor(dfCategory) {
    this.dfCategory = dfCategory;
    this.TotalAmount = 0;
    this.id = ++Category.id; // Create Unique Category ID
    Object.assign(this, Category.m.reduce((o,m)=>(o[m]=0,o),{}));
  }
  addAmount(m, v) {
    this[Category.m[m - 1]] += v;
    this.TotalAmount += v;
  }
}

const items = [
  {id:"1", dfCategory:"category 1", dfAmount:100, dfCreatedForMonth:"1"},
  {id:"2", dfCategory:"category 2", dfAmount:500, dfCreatedForMonth:"3"},
  {id:"3", dfCategory:"category 1", dfAmount:200, dfCreatedForMonth:"3"},
  {id:"4", dfCategory:"category 3", dfAmount:330, dfCreatedForMonth:"3"},
  {id:"5", dfCategory:"category 2", dfAmount:450, dfCreatedForMonth:"5"}
];

const All = items.reduce((M, item) => {
  const id = item.dfCategory;
  if (!M.has(id)) M.set(id, new Category(id));
  M.get(id).addAmount(item.dfCreatedForMonth, item.dfAmount);
  return M;
}, new Map());

console.log([...All.values()]);
```